# Determine if timedates are within a certain range

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists, the nested list is a list of timestamps with a minimum length of 4 going all the way up to 250. I know how to check if two timestamps are within a certain range however, How would you check if 3 are within a certain range?

```
master = [Timestamp('2014-03-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-03-12 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-03-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-29 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2014-03-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-01 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2013-08-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-08-13 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-09-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-09-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-09-24 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2014-04-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-11 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-04-30 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-15 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2014-05-21 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2012-11-16 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2012-11-28 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2012-12-09 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2012-12-10 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2012-12-22 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-14 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-31 00:00:00')]
[Timestamp('2012-11-23 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-01 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-02 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-07 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2013-01-17 00:00:00')]
final_result = []
for stamp in master:
    sub_list = []
    stamp = stamp.sort(reverse = True)
    x1 = stamp[0] - stamp[1]
    x2 = stamp[1] - stamp[2]
    if x1+x2 <=7:
         sub_list.append(1)
         continue
    else:
         sub_list.append(0)
if 1 in sub_list:
    final_result.append(1)
else:
    final_result.append(0)
```

This seems too bulky and inefficient. I also have to figure out how not to go past the range index.

Is there a better way?

Comment: Find the minimum and maximum and compare them.

Comment: I don't understand your goal.  Do you want to know if the TOTAL timespan is greater than 7?  Do you want to know whether ANY two dates in the last are more than 7 days apart?

Comment: I need to determine if any three log ins are within 7 days.  Basically, an earned customer is determined by 3 log-ins within 7 days.

Comment: Your code ins incomplete, for me it gives `NameError: name 'Timestamp' is not defined`. Please post a short but complete piece of code others can try.

Comment: Timestamp isn't a name it is a type